# How to handle exceptions in Robot Framework?

Tags: java, python, robotframework

I want to understand how Exception Handling is done in Robot. I want to handle exceptions from multiple testcases using some generic way.

Comment: What do you mean by "handle exceptions"? What exceptions? Exceptions in the application that is being tested?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below two keywords for that:

1. Run Keyword And Continue On Failure
2. Run Keyword And Ignore Error    based on ur requirement, however i suggest to go with 2nd one as you'll be able to store output and status

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can define a Test Teardown keyword. In my case (web automated solution) following happens:

```
# Following closes potential alert and saves what the alert says
${message} =    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Handle Alert    timeout=0s
# This is a keyword that empties download/upload directories and saves their content for future debugging
Save Artefacts    uploadDir=${global_uploadDir}    downloadDir=${global_downloadDir}    outputDir=${global_outputDir}    testStatus=${TEST STATUS}
# This keyword just captures a screenshot in case that test failed
Run Keyword If Test Failed    Capture Page Screenshot
```